# Azure uploaded VHD storage

Tags: azure, vhd

I'll preface this with being very new to Azure and I'm tying to learn as I go along here.

With Azure, I've uploaded a vhd image to a storage account, made an image out of that (which shows as a link to the file in the storage account) and finally created a vm from that image.

I can't seem to locate this in the documentation... but does this mean that the image is copied to the VM and I can delete the uploaded vhd file, or is it still using the vhd file?

Also, are the changes in this VHD then stored in LRS Snapshots?  My subscription indicates that I've used up my allotment of LRS Snapshot storage, but I've not configured any snapshots so can I assume this would be the deltas from the VHD?

Answer (score 0):

If you took the default options then your VM would have been created with a managed disk, this is a separate object in Azure, not something in your storage account. Take a look at the VM and the "disks" option, it should show you what disks are attached.
If you confirm you have a managed disk assigned, and it has correctly been created from your image, then you can delete the image (assuming you don't want to create any more machines from this image).

Comment: I see a disk listed under "OS disk" of storage type "Standard HDD", but I don't see any way to know if this is a managed disk or not.  The disk name is derived from the original name with "_disk1_" followed by a hex value... Does the name or the storage type indicate this is managed?  Clicking on the disk name, it says the disk state is "Reserved" but nothing else.

Comment: I was reading on a [different thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/718016/is-waagent-deprovision-necessary-for-migrating-an-azure-vm-to-another-subscri) here about creating a "disk" and not an "image".  Would the fact that I created an image from the VHD indicate that what I have is a managed disk?